Is there any way to find to primitive root of an word in the Bible?
I have a web project to help people doing research on inscriptions. In this project, I thought of a feature like this: While reading any Torah verse (just like on biblehub), users will be presented with a panel where each word (if it is not a conjunction, preposition, etc.) will be displayed and the primitive root of the word (usually consisting of 2 to 4 Hebrew letters) will be shown (if it is not a conjunction, preposition, etc.) and when they click on this root, they will be able to see all the words derived from this root and in which verses these words occur. This will provide information about the usage, context and semantic integrity of the word.
The problem is that I can't access this data in any way, I have looked in all the known databases but I can't find it, (Sefaria, Open Scriptures). Is there any way I can get it?
Let me illustrate what I am saying.
Please open the text analysis section for Genesis 1:3 on BibleHub. Here, for the word light, in the “Word Origin” section, press where it says “from or” and we have the root of this word. But this does not work for every word. BibleHub does not give this example for every word. For example, Genesis 1:5. Our word is night, code for strong: 3915. When we click on it, we get the following result: “Derived from an unused root”. But we know that the root of this word is “ליל”.  That's the main thing I want to find out, how can I access this data or is this data available on the internet? I've never come across it, and more importantly, how can I program this process. At the moment I have a database of all the words in the Torah with nikkud and simple forms.
Pardon for my English. Thanks.

You should be aware that "primitive roots" are constructs by lexicographers and vary from author to author and lexicon to lexicon.  One only need examine the marked differences between Strong's vs Kohlenberger in NT Greek and Strong's vs Baker and Carpenter in the Hebrew.

The following lexicon lists all the entries by their root. Before electronic versions, people had to guess the possible roots attempting to look up words.  Brown, F., Driver, S. R., & Briggs, C. A. (1977). In Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon. Clarendon Press.

A good place to search for words is an interlinear resource, like this one. You can chase the verses you would like to understand better and usually find a number of answers about the original languages. https://biblehub.com/interlinear/

ConcordancesThere are several biblical Concordances available, that contain every word used in the Holy Bible. For example, Strong's Exhaustive Concordance, and  Young's Exhaustive Concordance.
These give chapter and verse references to where each word is found. But they often give background material too. As you asked, the root words from which the Hebrew/Greek words were derived.
For a start, try these books. (Then, for deeper research, try exhaustive Hebrew or Greek Lexicons.
InternetWith the digital revolution, much information is indeed found on the Internet. Perhaps with much searching and interacting with other users, one can find the requested information. (Including asking Jewish rabbis for assistance, as I have done.) But still, a starting place might just as well be, the hard cover bookery!
